# How do I retrieve an element's id by its "value"?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am currently doing a Sharepoint customization and am running into a bit of an issue where I need to call a function if a particular element id is selected. The problem is that the element ID changes every time we install the Sharepoint instance so what I am aiming to do is identify the element id by its "value". To give my question some context, this is the html (which cannot be altered):

```
<span class="ms-RadioText" title="Yes"><input id="378Ukj200" name="radio_button" value="ctl00" checked="checked" type="radio"><label for="378Ukj200">Yes</label></span>
<span class="ms-RadioText" title="No"><input id="378Ukj201" name="radio_button" value="ctl01" type="radio"><label for="378Ukj201">No</label></span>
```

And these are the current getElementID based statements (which won't work once we more the instance to a production box):

```
document.getElementByID('378Ukj200').onclick = new Function('checkForRadioChange("Yes");');
document.getElementByID('378Ukj201').onclick = new Function('checkForRadioChange("No");');
```

I was hoping to even achieve something to the effect of this using the span tag, for example (of course this would never work for multiple reasons):

```
var rispan = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for( var i = 0, j= rispan.length; i < j; i+=1 ) {
    var classes = span[i].getAttribute("title");
    if( classes ) {
       if( classes.indexOf("Yes") != -1) {
          onclick = new Function('checkForRadioChange("Yes");');
       }
       else if( classes.indexOf("No") != -1) {
          onclick = new Function('checkForRadioChange("No");');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you wrap your functions inside a Function instance `new Function()` ?

Comment: What are the several reasons?  It seems like this would mostly work except you need the corresponding input element for onclick

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen for added bad-assery! (duh)

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Previous developers. We are hoping to eradicate this kind of crap but in the meantime the client is flogging us with a whip to get this thing up and running again.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I've probably been awake for too long, but that's pretty much what I'm stuck on, I'm needing a way to pick up the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input is seemingly the only input child of the span, it's fairly trivial to get:

```
var input = rispan[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
...
input.onclick = new Function ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Y74bn/

---

You should use `function () {}` syntax to define anonymous functions.  `new Function` doesn't seem to be working so well for you.  Additionally, `onlick` is antiquated and evil!  You should use `addEventListener`, if it exists.  Otherwise, `attachEvent`.

Comment: I like what you've suggested but I am a little confused, are you suggesting I could use this for both of the spans?

Comment: @Switchkick yes; `getElementsByTagName` is a method that is available to all nodes including the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

I would put my code inside a div with fixed id, then get the the children.

```
var nodes = document.getElementByID('div_id').children;
```

With this i would test for tagName in a loop and attach the onclick event where it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Structure to match:

```
<span class="ms-RadioText" title="Yes">
    <input id="378Ukj200" name="radio_button" value="ctl00" checked="checked" type="radio">
    <label for="378Ukj200">Yes</label>
</span>
```

CSS selector for the input element:

```
span.ms-RadioText[title="Yes"] > input[name="radio_button"]
```

Use a library that allows CSS selectors. Win.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what level of compatibility you need but in modern browsers it can be as simple as:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[title^="ctl"]');

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  var label = input.nextSibling;

  input.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (label.textContent == 'Yes') {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why `[].forEach.call(inputs, function () {});` instead of `inputs.forEach(function () {});`? I prefer the shorter one, but does it make any difference?

Comment: @elclanrs This solution works fantastically in Firefox but all versions of IE throw a TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined error. Is that what you were alluding to? Or have I missed something in my implementation?

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen: `inputs` is a NodeList (array-like object) _not_ a regular array, therefore it doesn't have array methods available. Try your solution, it won't work, it will tell you something like "_Object #<NodeList> has no method 'forEach'_"

Comment: @elclanrs ah, thanks for clearing that up. I actually DID try your example but failed to create a good setup; I used a regular array instead of a NodeList.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen: How do you use a regular array? Elements from the DOM are always retrieved either as `Node` or as `NodeList` none of which is an real array, unless you're already converting to an array like `[].slice.call(els).forEach(function(){`..